# Problem with the proof 0f " the intersection of closed sets is closed".

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have been reading this text http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_REAL_ANALYSIS.PDF, and before I address my main question, I want to note that the author, in the same section, mentioned that for the complement of any set  $S$ we are always considering the elements that are not in $S$ but in the universal, that is the reals:

[image]

[image]

Now, the proof that the intersection of a closed set is closed is given as:

[image]

The only problem I have with understanding proof (b) is that the complement of $T$, in this context, is the set of all numbers that are not members of $T$ but members of the reals, but, we are told that the complement of $T$ is the union of the complements of all of the sets $F$ which would infer that there is no element of at least one $F$ that is not an element of $T$. Yet, this is a contradiction to $T$ being an intersection of the sets $F$, as it states that $T$ is equal to all of the $F$s, or in other words, $T$ contains every element of every $F$. So, my question is:

In this context, is the complement of $T$ still defined in terms of the reals or is it defined relatively $T$? For, if it is defined relatively, then I can progress with the proof since I know the proof for the relative complement of an intersection.

(Note: I had a look at this question [Proof of complement of intersection defined using an arbitrary set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385129/proof-of-complement-of-intersection-defined-using-an-arbitrary-set) and it seems that the complement is defined relatively. Also, sorry if this question doesn't make sense but this particular part of the proof just doesn't make sense to me at all.)

Comment: It seems you're getting the definition of intersection wrong. T is the set of things that the F's all have in common. If there is even one F with $x\not\in F$, then $x\not\in T$.

Comment: @SE318 I thought that is how I was treating the definition of the intersection in my question. I merely stated that there can eixst an ${x}\in{F}$ s.t. ${x}\notin{T}$ since otherwise would mean that $T =f$ ($f$ is supposed to mean the collection of all $F$s here). Thus, it should be quite clear that the complement of $T$ cannot be the union of the complements of all $F$ since there could possibly be an element of one $F$ that is not an element of $T$.

Comment: Definition of Intersection: $\displaystyle \bigcap_i X_i$ is the set of $x$ s.t. $x \in X_1, x \in X_2, \ldots, x \in X_i, \ldots$

Comment: @ChinmayNirkhe  I follow that, but what I am saying is that since that is true it means that not all elements of $f$ are elements of $T$ and thusly not all elements of each $F$ is an element of $T$. So, if we want the set of all real numbers that are not element of $T$ (the complement of $T$) we cannot say that the the union of all the complements of all of the $F$s is equal to the complement of $T$ since there may be an element originally in $F$ that was not in $T$, and by taking its complement we are dismissing that number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to understand that the problem is the equality $\left( \bigcap A_n\right)^C=\bigcup A_n^C$. So let's take an element $x\in \left( \bigcap A\right)^C$ then there is an $A_n$ such that $x\notin A_n$ which means $x\in A_n^C$ and then $x\in \bigcup A_n^C$. Now let's take $x\in \bigcup A_n^C$ then there is some $A_n$ for which $x\notin A_n$ and then $x\in \left( \bigcap A\right)^C$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I could not believe it was this. I have an irregular tendency to unnecessarily obfuscate things.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in T^c$ then $x\not\in T$. Then there exists $F_a$. such that $x\not\in F_a$. Then $x\in F_a^c$. Then $x\in\bigcup F^c$.

For the other direction, let $x\in\bigcup F^c$. then there exists $F_b^c$ with $x\in F_b^c$. Thus $x\not\in F_b$. Then $x\not\in T$ so $x\in T^c$.

Comment: Thanks, but I think in the last words of the sentence you mean to say that $x$ is an element of the complement of $T$.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Typing Tex on a smartphone is a challenge!